# Reactjs trying to merge arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, store

Let's say I have two array's

```
let array1 = ["H","E","", "","O","","","R","L","D"];
let array2 = ["","","L","L","","W","O","","",""];
```

I want to merge them such that they would then contain:

```
array3 = ["H","E","L", "L","O","W","O","R","L","D"];
```

How would I achieve this?
To be more clear I have a target array which is array3 an empty array and then I'm generating random characters and if they match array3 adding them to the blank array in the specific position with react state. It is just not storing the position and character each time but just changing it. SO my idea is to set the state such that I merge the current state with the new characters that are found.

TLDR:- Brute forcing Hello World meme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array `array3` out of iterating over `array1` and get the `l` (letters) and if any `l` evaluates to `falsey` then get the letter at the same `i` (index) in the `array2`.

Note that instead of declaring your arrays with `let` you should always use `const` because it makes code easier to read within its scope, and `const` variable always refers to the same object.

Code example:

```js
const array1 = ["H","E","", "","O","","","R","L","D"];
const array2 = ["","","L","L","","W","O","","",""];

const array3 = array1.map((l, i) => l || array2[i]);

console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
let arr1 = ["H","E","", "","O","","","R","L","D"];
let arr2 = ["","","L","L","","W","O","","",""];
let arr3 = [];

arr1.forEach((val, index) => {
  if (val === '') {
    arr3[index] = arr2[index];
  } else {
    arr3[index] = val;
  }
});
console.log(arr3);
```